# Json to javascript object

Tags: jquery, json

`I need help to convert json to javascript object` so as to `allow me to access` it like that  `"json.data.audience.infomation"` to `get the values in the json arrays?`

because I would like to use the values inside to do "if else comparison"

This is My json structure :

```
{
            "data": [
                     {
                         "id": "/en/chelsea_fc",
                         "topic": "Chelsea F.C.",
                         "audience": [
                             {
                                 "userid": "100003914111287",
                                 "information": [
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Didier Drogba"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Frank Lampard"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Professional sports team",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "favorite_teams",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     }
                                 ]
                             },
                             {
                                 "userid": "100003914111287",
                                 "information": [
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Didier Drogba"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Frank Lampard"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Professional sports team",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "favorite_teams",
                                         "source": "Chelsea Football Club"
                                     }
                                 ]
                             }
                         ],
                         "type": "/soccer/football_team"
                     },
                     {
                         "id": "/en/manchester_united_fc",
                         "topic": "Manchester United F.C.",
                         "audience": [
                             {
                                 "information": [
                                     {
                                         "category": "Athlete",
                                         "source": "Ryan Giggs"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "Professional sports team",
                                         "source": "Manchester United"
                                     },
                                     {
                                         "category": "favorite_teams",
                                         "source": "Manchester United"
                                     }
                                 ],
                                 "userid": "100003921730958"
                             }
                         ],
                         "type": "/soccer/football_team"
                     }
                 ]
             }
```

Comment: Where do you get this json string from?

Comment: Dupe of a dupe of a dupe... have you tried searching?

Comment: Are you asking how to access what you need or how to generate the JSON that will allow you to use the expression in your question?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I need to access what I need because I wanted to match data from another json file.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want with

```
json.data[0].audience.infomation
```

Note that the other object is wrapped in an array.

This is a *JavaScript* object, not a *Java* object.

Answer (score 1):

Use $.parseJSON of the jquery library. It returns a JQuery object after parsing

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: or you can use `JSON.parse` that `$.parseJSON` wraps.

Answer (score 0):

To convert JSON to JavaScript, simply 'eval' it. I would recommend [reading this short tutorial.](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: `eval` per se is not recommended

Comment: @JanDvorak - true, but this guy is clearly a n00b. Before pointing them at jQuery, they should probably learn about the relationship between JSON and JavaScript.

Comment: Also note the question is tagged jQuery, so jQuery is probably safe to use ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have arrays in your json structure so you have to access them like this:

```
 console.log(jsn.data[0].audience[0].information[0].category);

 output is: **Athlete**
```

This will `log the category`

in

which is `first array item of information`

which is `first array item of audience`

which is `first array item of data`

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JAUDn/